Can I use an Ethernet cable to connect a PBX module to a doorphone unit over an 80m distance?
I'm looking for advice on connecting a Panasonic NS500 PBX module (which supports Ethernet sockets and plugs) to a doorphone unit. The distance between the doorphone and the PBX is roughly 80 meters.

Is it possible to use an Ethernet cable for this connection?
If so, what copper section would be required for proper operation over this distance?
What type of Ethernet cable (Cat5e, Cat6, etc.) would be best suited for a stable connection?
I’d appreciate any insights or recommendations based on similar setups or experiences.

IIRC good Cat-5e should support 100 and 1000 Mbit/s to 100m. So I expect it should be fine.

@GiacomoCatenazzi, since you could potentially use any copper cable, which in case would be recommended using mmq units which would allow increasing copper section (1,5g mmq or 2,5g mmq) depending on distance, however it looks like Ethernet cable do not offer this kind of spec...

If you don't have the installation manual, we really don't know what cables you can use and how long they can be. Also they are not Ethernet cables but cables you can use for Ethernet and many other structured telecommunications and networking purposes as well.

The Ethernet standard defines maximum cable lengths, but those take into account not only the physical cable but the way in which it's used electrically and the sorts of signals that are sent along it.
This product is using Ethernet cables but is not using them for Ethernet. It's likely that they've chosen to use Ethernet cables because of their wide availability; it does not seem to be using the cable in a way which exploits the cable's ability to achieve long run lengths (i.e. differential signaling along twisted pairs). Of course, it may also be attempting much lower bitrates than Ethernet, and may be sending analog data which degrades more smoothly, so that doesn't necessarily mean the thing won't work at long distances.
The bottom line is that if the maximum cable length is not stated in the documentation or available from the manufacturer then your only option is to test it out and hope that your tests encompass the entire range of conditions that it'll be expected to work in.
